# TailwindCSS visibility toggle on hover fails only on localhost

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to get TailwindCSS to show a div only when hovering over it. Here is an example that works:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/h9qHA6gSVF

I've re-created this same example in my project, which has a fairly boilerplate tailwind setup. It works when deployed:

https://staging.transfigurism.org/test

But the hover doesn't work when I run it on my localhost. I don't see any errors in the console and am struggling to figure out what might be different. Any suggestions?

Comment: are other styles or states(for eg. disabled) working?

Comment: Is this a specific problem with the hover, or are none of the other Tailwind styles applied?

Comment: @EduardoMottadeMoraes seems to be a specific problem with hover.

Comment: @HarshitT yes, other styles like hidden and disabled work.

Comment: I've temporarily exposed my localhost via ngrok here. The error is showing up there.

https://73db-136-36-205-87.ngrok.io/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.group` and related classes are not present in the bundled CSS in your assets folder in the localhost. In the deployed bundle they're there. You can check this in the "Sources" tab in your browser dev tools.

[image]

This could happen for more than one reason, so you'll have to do some debugging.

I'd suggest you start with the following:

(1) Make sure Tailwind is updating the bundled CSS after your edits, especially classes other than `group`, `hover` and `visible`. If it's not, then it's probably some problem in its configuration. Remove it and try installing it again following [these steps](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/remix) if you haven't already.

(2) Downgrade to a previous version of Tailwind.